# search destinations by name AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

this is the code of the textbox of destinations on view page

```
<input name="states" id="city"
      style="margin-left: 0px;margin-right: 109px; font-size: 14px"
      type="text" placeholder="Any worldwide city or airport" 
      ng-model="selectedNumberNonEditable" allow-custom="false"
      typeahead="state as state.name + '' + state.code + '' for state in states | filter:{code:$viewValue} | limitTo:8"
      class="form-control" required>
```

this is the searchcontroller.js

```
 var states = [
  { 'name': 'Ansan, South Korea', 'code': '(A1N)' },
  { 'name': 'Asan, South Korea', 'code': '(A1S)' },   
  { 'name': 'Atascadero - CA, United States', 'code': '(AA1)' },     
  { 'name': 'Arlon, Belgium', 'code': '(AAO)' },
   { 'name': 'London, United Kingdom', 'code': '(LON)' },

]
```

in this case only display  the results what we search by the code.i want to display the results when i search the destination name too.

**Search By Airpot**
[image: Search By Airpot]

**Search by Name of city**
[image: Search by Name of city]

please  help me.

Answer (score 0):

Harsha,

Seems you're not mapping the object with input field

First 
replace this

```
 var states
```

with

```
 $scope.states
```

to filter the results you can refer angular filters like below example

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">

  <p><input type="text" ng-model="test"></p>

 <ul>
   <li ng-repeat="x in names | filter : test">
   {{ x }}
  </li>
 </ul>
```

detailed example 
https://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_filters_input

Comment: that's not an issue.it works fine.didn't clear your answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to change you `input` as below

```
<input name="states" id="city" style="margin-left: 0px;margin-right: 109px; font-size: 14px" type="text" placeholder="Any worldwide city or airport" ng-model="selectedNumberNonEditable" allow-custom="false" typeahead="state as state.name + '' + state.code + '' for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control" required>
```

I have removed `code` from filter.

Comment: no.i want to filter those by code first.And the second priority to the name.